# Why is python not stripping?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list, whereby all elements are filenames from a folder. When it is made into a list, it is ['me.txt', 'you.txt', 'him.txt', 'her.txt']. However, I want to make it ['me', 'you', 'him', 'her']. I used the strip function .strip(".txt") but it is still printing out the former. Any help?

```
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    files.extend(filenames)
    for filenames in files:
        filenames = filenames.strip(".txt")
    print(files)
```

Comment: Beware, `str.strip()` does not work the way you seem to think it works. Try `"trust.txt".strip(".txt")`, and see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually *changing* the item in the array; you're changing a copy of it created by a `for` loop. You'd be better using a list comprehension, which generates a new list by applying something to the existing one:

```
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    files.extend(filenames)
    files = [file.strip(".txt") for file in files]
    print(files)
```

You could also use the `map` function to apply a function to each item:

```
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
    files.extend(filenames)
    files = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(".txt"), files))
    print(files)
```

Comment: @Eric1108 No problem! Please remember to accept answers that have helped you.

Comment: sorry, im new to stack overflow. didnt know about accepting answers

Comment: Saying "a copy of it created by a `for` loop" makes it seem like if you loop over an iterable with a `for` loop, you get copies of the objects in the loop and not references to the objects themselves.